# Best practices on the clientside and the serveside with DOM scripting and PHP

Tags: php, dom

What it the best practices with for example Dom scripting on the client and serverside with php.
What should you do with dom and what with php, can I skip installing php and do everything with dom as with php?

Comment: PHP and JavaScript both implement the W3C's DOM interface. JavaScript can be used server side as well. What you choose to use depends on your project. You may want to refine the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, you cannot skip PHP. With DOM you won't get any data from database etc.

- Javascript is to enhance user experience. Nothing less, nothing more.
- Server-side processing is for actual data operations (fetching, storing and computing).

Comment: JavaScript can do more than that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript

Comment: Well, yes, but it's rather un-used technology. I'm not sure, but I understood the question more like 'client-side vs server-side'.